# Spring data stream InboundChannelAdapter have different behaviour with different return type

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-cloud-stream

I am using spring cloud stream, and facing an issue, when I am using  InboundChannelAdapter with return type MessageSource, then is behaving like a singleton class, it's running in every 1 second and sending the same data to the consumer. Also, the logger is printing them out only one time when application startup.

```
 @InboundChannelAdapter(value = Source.OUTPUT, poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
    public MessageSource<String> uuidSource() {
        UuidCaller uuidCaller = new UuidCaller(atomicLong.addAndGet(1), new Date(), UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        logger.info("buid request:"+uuidCaller);
        return () ->  MessageBuilder.withPayload(uuidCaller.toString()).build();
    }
```

but where I have changed to MessageSource to simple to String type then its working fine

```
InboundChannelAdapter(value = Source.OUTPUT, poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
    public String uuidSource() {
        UuidCaller uuidCaller = new UuidCaller(atomicLong.addAndGet(1), new Date(), UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        logger.info("build request:"+uuidCaller);
        return uuidCaller.toString();
    }
```

it's sending consumer to updated data and also printing the update log in every second.

So my question is why different behaviour for different return type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it's a MessageSource it must also be annotated with '@Bean'. Hence the UUID is only created once. When it's a POJO method it's created on each poll.

If you move the UUID Into the lambda they will work the same.

**EDIT**

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = Source.OUTPUT, poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
public MessageSource<String> uuidSource() {
    return () -> {
        UuidCaller uuidCaller = new UuidCaller(atomicLong.addAndGet(1), new Date(), UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        logger.info("buid request:"+uuidCaller);
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(uuidCaller.toString()).build();
    };
}
```

Comment: Hello Gray, Thanks for your response, I have added @Bean on MessageSource, but it still the sending a single copy(as singleton) of UuidCaller in every 1 sec, not printing anything (log).
Can you please write the how i can move the UUID Into the lambda (eg code).
Thank you!

Comment: Thanks sir. I am big fan of spring team. Thanks for your valuable response.